# dynamic change of variable to ngmodel is not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to make date change dynamically and get  date reflected in view but  it is not getting reflected.When date is hard-coded like this in an array it is getting reflected in view.
My  `date : Array<String> = ['2020-02-25'];` is getting reflected in view.But my date which is changed after a post subscription is not getting reflected.Here is the code for that.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sendPostRequest();
  }


sendPostRequest()  {

      var options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }) };

      this.http.post("http://localhost/android/Api.php?apicall=getattendance", this.postData,options)

      .subscribe(data => {

        let key, count = 0;
for(key in data) {

 this.date.push(data[count]['date']);

 count++;
}
```

The view for that is

```
  <ion-calendar [(ngModel)]="date"
                  (change)="onChange($event)"
                  [options]="options"
                  type="string"
                  format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                  readonly="true"

                  >
    </ion-calendar>
```

ng-model accepts change from date which is given as hard coded.But `this.date` is not getting reflected.

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of date">
    <p>{{ item}}</p>

</div>
```

is also outputing only the dates that is hardcoded as 2020-02-05

Comment: What is the Change Detection strategy for your component (you can find this in the @Component decorator)? Is it OnPush strategy?

Comment: @Component({
  selector: 'app-c',
  templateUrl: './c.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./c.page.scss'],
})

Comment: Looks like the view you should update out of the box without any problems. Not sure what is the problem. Can you share a minimal version of your app in Stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few limitations to ngModel. Since you have `(change)` function, you can assign the changed value to `this.date`

```
 onChange(event){
     this.date = event.target.value
 }
```

Comment: thaks Srikara B S for answering my query